# Conditionally mount Windows partition

Tags: centos, mount, dual-boot, automounting, readonly

Since I'm using dual-boot (Windows 10 / CentOS 7) I want some files to be shared between the two OS, such as music, photos, etc. So I thought that it would be nice to auto-mount my Windows data-partition during start up.
However, this is not always possible because I needed to hibernate Windows, reboot in Linux to do something and then get back on Windows again.

So, how can I auto-mount this partition during boot, but with the condition that: "if it's been detected as "unclean", mount it read-only"?

Answer (score 1):

Create a FUSE helper in `/usr/bin` that attempts a `rw` mount and, if that fails, retries with a `ro` mount. (In case you're not familiar with FUSE, it's a subsystem that allows [user code to manage custom filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace).)

Create the file `/usr/bin/windowsfs` with the following contents. Make it executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
mount "$@" || mount "$@" -o ro
```

Install the `fuse` package (I'm not sure of the name on CentOS, but it's the one that provides the tools and subsystem to support FUSE filesystems).

Use a line such as this in your `/etc/fstab`, which declares your Windows partition `/dev/sda2` as being of type `fuse.windowsfs` and to be mounted on `/mnt/dsk`

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt/dsk fuse.windowsfs defaults 0 0
```

When this line is acted upon, it calls the FUSE helper `/usr/bin/windowfs` to mount the partition. This is our script that attempts a writeable mount but falls back to a read-only mount if necessary.

A standard `umount /mnt/dsk` operation is sufficient to unmount the partition after use.

---

A more robust `windowsfs` script might look like this, where you would get the error message from the "normal" mount if both mounts failed:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
exec 3>&1
error1=$(mount "$@" 2>&1 1>&3); ss1=$? ss2=0
[[ 0 -lt $ss1 ]] && { error2=$(mount "$@" -o ro 2>&1 1>&3); ss2=$?; }
[[ 0 -lt $ss2 ]] && { error="$error1" ss=$ss1; } || { error="$error2" ss=$ss2; }

[[ 0 -lt $ss ]] && echo "$error" >&2
exit $ss
```